# SQL generate ranks of groups and subgroups based on third column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to write a SQL query to generate ranks of groups and subgroups based on third column (Price in this case). While i know we can use dense_rank() to generate ranks based on one column. I have no idea how to generate the two columns of ranks as shown below in a single query.

Both the rankings are based on price. So J3 comes first because J3 sum(price) is 1600. J1 comes second because J1 sum(price) is 1500 and so on.

Any inputs are appreciated.

I have provided the sample input and output. The name of the input table is "RENTAL"

[image]

Comment: I have no idea how the ordering for `rank_jet` is determined.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)  -- Yes that means you have to **try** before asking and include your code

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results in table form

Comment: @DanielMarcus -  am not sure if the table is not visible. I have provided both input and output.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - it is done with price. Edited the question to make it more clearer. Hope it helps!

Comment: @rAmAnA, how exactly is price determining rank_jet here ?

Comment: @DanielMarcus - If you sum(price) in J3 category it is 1600. If you sum(price) in J1 category it is 1500 and for J2 it is 800. This determines rank_jet.

Comment: @rAmAnA, thanks got it now - please let me know if updated answer works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First roll up jet_type prices to the jet_type level, then create a ranking of all jet_types ordered by rolled up price, and finally use your window function in the outer query partitioned by jet_price and ordered by highest rolled up price to create rank_service_wthin_jet:

```
select a.jet_type, b.rownum rank_jet, a.service_type, a.price, 
  row_number() over(partition by a.jet_type order by a.price desc) rank_service_wthin_jet
  from yourtable a join (
  select jet_type, row_number() over(order by price desc) rownum from (
  select  jet_type, sum(price) price from yourtable
  group by jet_type)a)b on a.jet_type=b.jet_type
```

Comment: If rank_jet correlates to jet_type then why do you need it?

Comment: rank_jet does not correlate to jet_type.

Comment: @rAmAnA seems from your example they are 1:1

Comment: it would be very helpful if you can also provide a brief explanation. Also, upvoting the question might help others. Does this kind of a scenario have a special name, which I am not aware of?

Comment: Noone is going to upvote the question because you did not provide the data for us in table form.  Providing the data as a pic makes it very hard to work with.

Comment: Okay. When it said table format, i thought it meant arranged in rows and columns. Anyway question is solved and i learned something, so all fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate two columns as:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by jet_type) as rank_jet,
       row_number() over (partition by jet_type order by price desc) as rank_service_within_jet
. . .
```

This does not exactly return what is in your table.  But the results are quite similar and -- even more important -- make sense.

Comment: Please refer to the output table now. The jet_category ranks are important because we are first ranking by them and then sub ranking by the service_type provided in Jet.